# Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<xxx>'

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I tryed following transaction in typescript.
But it omit compile error like below. it says `Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<transactionArgument>'`
but this function return `transaction` which type is `transactionArgument`

So I wonder why this occured,
if someone has opinion,will you please let me know

```
type RegisterPricingTransactionInfo = (pricingTransaction:transactionArgument,createdAt:Date,createdBy:string,datasource:any) => Promise<transactionArgument>

export const  registerPricingTransactionInfo: RegisterPricingTransactionInfo = async (pricingTransaction,createdAt,createdBy,datasource) => {
    let urlCode;
    let transaction:transactionArgument;
    transaction = {test:"test"}

     await datasource.manager.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager:EntityManager) =>{
     try {
        await transactionalEntityManager.save(transaction)
        return transaction;
     } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
     }
    })
}
```

```
    "message": "Type '(pricingTransaction: transactionArgument, createdAt: Date, createdBy: string, datasource: any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'RegisterPricingTransactionInfo'.\n  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<transactionArgument>'.\n    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'transactionArgument'.",
```

Thanks..

Comment: You don't return anything from the `catch`. You might want to let the error propagate to the caller (i.e. don't  catch it)  or make the return type `Promise<transactionArgument | void>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested callback. It properly returns data, but the parent function does not.

Proper code indentation may help spot the issue:

```
const registerPricingTransactionInfo: RegisterPricingTransactionInfo = async (pricingTransaction,createdAt,createdBy,datasource) => {
  let urlCode;
  let transaction:transactionArgument;
  transaction = {test: "test"}

  await datasource.manager.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager: EntityManager) => {
    try {
      await transactionalEntityManager.save(transaction)
      return transaction; // nested callback return
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
  });
  // no return?
}
```